# I need help updating my JTextPane by adding a strikethrough

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextpane, strikethrough

I am working on a user-interface and I have a `JTextPane` in a `JPanel` and in the `JTextPane` I have added strings using `JTextPane.getStyledDocument().insertString()`. Now I want to update the `JTextPane` and put a strike through through those words.

How do I go about updating the words after a `JButton` is clicked? I don't want all the strings in the `JTextPane` to get a strike-through, just certain ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In actionListener of jButton try this.

```
jTextPane.setContentType( "text/html" );
jTextPane.setText("<strike> Words to strike </strike> Words not to Strike");
```

Use your logic to strike the required words.

You can use `jTextPane.getSelectedText()` or `jTextPane.getText();`

Comment: The OP asked to strike through **particular words** inside the `JTextPane`.

Comment: Thanks RealSkeptic ! @OP Will this do ?

Comment: it did strikethrough it. now im going to work around the logic of the certain words to strike. thanks alot!

Comment: @realSkeptic im going to try and figure out how to strike the particular words and if im stuck ill let you guys knows. thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help!, Please accept the answer, if your problem is solved.

Comment: only one word prints out with the strikethrough. the other words get lost. i did  [ "<strike>" + string[i] ]